# How to have clear button on my calculator using javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am kind of having trouble on making my clear function works on my calculator

This is my HTML:

```html
<input type="button" id="result" value="C" onClick="clr()">
<input type="button" name="greater" value="<" onClick="calcNumbers(greater.value)">
<input type="button" name="divb" value="/" onClick="calcNumbers(divb.value)">
<input type="button" name="mulb" value="*" onClick="calcNumbers(mulb.value)">
```

and this is my JavaScript

```js
function calcNumbers(result) {
  form.displayResult.value = form.displayResult.value + result;
}
```

Comment: What is the logic behind the `clr()` method? Where is the rest of your markup and JS logic?

Comment: ```function clr(){ form.displayResult.value = ""}``` is that what you want?

Answer (score 0):

Wrap all the input fields inside form tag or div tag and give id to that tag, ... and in script tag add function and rest it as document.getElementById("myForm").reset();

Answer (score 0):

```
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head runat="server">
    <title></title>
    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">

    function Add() {
        var x, y, txtResult;
        x = document.getElementById('txtFirst').value;
        y = document.getElementById('txtSecond').value;
        if (x == " " || y == "") {
            alert("Please enter FirstValue and SecondValue");
        }
       else{
        var txtResult = +x + +y;
        document.getElementById('txtResult').innerHTML = "Result: " + txtResult;
        }
    }

    function Sub() {
        var x, y, txtResult;
        x = document.getElementById('txtFirst').value;
        y = document.getElementById('txtSecond').value;
        if (x == " " || y == "") {
            alert("Please enter FirstValue and SecondValue");
        } else {
            var txtResult = +x - +y;
            document.getElementById('txtResult').innerHTML = "Result: " + txtResult;
        }
    }
    function Mul() {
        var x, y, txtResult;
        x = document.getElementById('txtFirst').value;
        y = document.getElementById('txtSecond').value;
        if (x == " " || y == "") {
            alert("Please enter FirstValue and SecondValue");
        } else {
            var txtResult = +x * +y;
            document.getElementById('txtResult').innerHTML = "Result: " + txtResult;
        }
    }

    function Div() {
        var x, y, txtResult;
        x = document.getElementById('txtFirst').value;
        y = document.getElementById('txtSecond').value;
         if (x == " " || y == "") {
            alert("Please enter FirstValue and SecondValue");
             } 
        else if (y != 0) {
            var txtResult = +x / +y;
              } 
        else {
            alert("Second Number Should not be Zero");
                }
        document.getElementById('txtResult').innerHTML = "Result: " + txtResult;
      }

    function Clear() {
        document.getElementById('txtFirst').value = "";
        document.getElementById('txtSecond').value = "";
        document.getElementById('txtResult').value = "";

    }


</script>
</head>
<body>
<form id="form1" runat="server">
<div>
    <label> FirstNumber :</label><br />
    <input id="txtFirst" type="text" /><br />
    <label> Second Number :</label><br />
    <input id="txtSecond" type="text" /><br />
    <label id="txtResult"></label><br />
    <input id="btnAdd" type="button" value="ADD" onclick="Add()"/>
    <input id="btnSub" type="button" value="SUB"  onclick="Sub()"/><br />
    <input id="btnMul" type="button" value="MUL" onclick="Mul()"/>
    <input id="btnDiv" type="button" value="DIV" onclick="Div()"/>
   <input id="btnClear" type="button" value="Clear" onclick="Clear()"/>


   </div>
   </form>
   </body>
   </html>
```

[Calculator image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iu5s5.png)

Answer (score 0):

You can clear the text by setting the value to an empty string.

```js
const form = document.querySelector('.calculator > form');

const handleMemoryClear = (v) => {
  const disp = form.querySelector('.display');
  disp.value = '';
};

const handleMemoryRecall = (v) => console.log('Implement MEMORY_RECALL');
const handleMemoryAdd    = (v) => console.log('Implement MEMORY_ADD');
const handleMemoryRemove = (v) => console.log('Implement MEMORY_REMOVE');

const handleOpAdd  = (v) => console.log('Implement OP_ADD');
const handleOpSub  = (v) => console.log('Implement OP_SUB');
const handleOpMul  = (v) => console.log('Implement OP_MUL');
const handleOpDiv  = (v) => console.log('Implement OP_DIV');
const handleOpEval = (v) => console.log('Implement OP_EVAL');

const handleTypeIn = (v) => {
  const disp = form.querySelector('.display');
  disp.value += v;
};

const handleTypeOp = (v) => {
  switch (v) {
    case '+': return handleOpAdd();
    case '-': return handleOpSub();
    case '×': return handleOpMul();
    case '÷': return handleOpDiv();
    case '=': return handleOpEval();
  }
}

const handleTypeFn = (v) => {
  switch (v) {
    case 'MC': return handleMemoryClear();
    case 'MR': return handleMemoryRecall();
    case 'M+': return handleMemoryAdd();
    case 'M-': return handleMemoryRemove();
  }
}

const handleButtonPress = (button, type) => {
  switch (type) {
    case 'in': return handleTypeIn(button.textContent);
    case 'op': return handleTypeOp(button.textContent);
    case 'fn': return handleTypeFn(button.textContent);
  }
};

const ignoreSubmission  = e => e.preventDefault();
const handleFormInput = e => {
  if (e.target instanceof HTMLButtonElement && e.target.dataset.type) {
    handleButtonPress(e.target, e.target.dataset.type);
  }
};

form.addEventListener('submit', ignoreSubmission);
form.addEventListener('click', handleFormInput);
```

```css
:root {
  --root-bg: #222;
  --root-fg: #EEE;
  --calc-bg: #444;
  --calc-border: #888;
  --calc-disp-bg: #333;
  --calc-disp-fg: #EEE;
  --calc-btn-bg: #444;
  --calc-btn-fg: #EEE;
  --calc-btn-hover-bg: #888;
}

html, body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  background: var(--root-bg);
  color: var(--root-fg);
}

.calculator {
  display: flex;
  padding: 0.25em;
  background: var(--calc-bg);
  border: thin solid var(--calc-border);
  align-items: center;
}

.calc-input {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(4, 1fr);
  grid-gap: 0.25em;
}

.calc-input > .display {
  grid-column-start: 1;
  grid-column-end: 5;
  grid-row-start: 1;
  grid-row-end: 1;
  font-size: 1.5em;
  background: var(--calc-disp-bg);
  border: thin solid var(--calc-border);
  color: var(--calc-disp-fg);
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: right;
  padding: 0.25em;
}

.calc-key {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 1.125em;
  font-weight: bold;
  border: thin solid var(--calc-border);
  background: var(--calc-btn-bg);
  color: var(--calc-btn-fg);
  padding: 0.25em 0;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.calc-key:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
  background: var(--calc-btn-hover-bg);
}

.calc-key[data-type="fn"] {
  background: #06D;
}

.calc-key[data-type="fn"]:hover {
  background: #08F;
}

.calc-key[data-type="op"] {
  background: #D60;
}

.calc-key[data-type="op"]:hover {
  background: #F80;
}
```

```html
<div class="calculator">
  <form class="calc-input">
    <input type="text" class="display" placeholder="0" />
    <button class="calc-key" data-type="fn">MC</button>
    <button class="calc-key" data-type="fn">M+</button>
    <button class="calc-key" data-type="fn">M-</button>
    <button class="calc-key" data-type="fn">MR</button>
    <button class="calc-key" data-type="in">7</button>
    <button class="calc-key" data-type="in">8</button>
    <button class="calc-key" data-type="in">9</button>
    <button class="calc-key" data-type="op">÷</button>
    <button class="calc-key" data-type="in">4</button>
    <button class="calc-key" data-type="in">5</button>
    <button class="calc-key" data-type="in">6</button>
    <button class="calc-key" data-type="op">×</button>
    <button class="calc-key" data-type="in">1</button>
    <button class="calc-key" data-type="in">2</button>
    <button class="calc-key" data-type="in">3</button>
    <button class="calc-key" data-type="op">-</button>
    <button class="calc-key" data-type="in">0</button>
    <button class="calc-key" data-type="in">.</button>
    <button class="calc-key" data-type="op">=</button>
    <button class="calc-key" data-type="op">+</button>
  </form>
</div>
```